# Unity MonoDevelop Auto Indent for if statements

Tags: unity-game-engine, monodevelop

The auto indent in MonoDevelop is behaving in a strange way.  When I add the closing braces it formats my code like this:

```
    if (joints.Length != 1) {
                    IntegrationTest.Fail ("Cat1 should have 1 HingeJoint2D, but has " + joints.Length);
            }
```

I would prefer it to format it like this:

```
    if (joints.Length != 1) {
        IntegrationTest.Fail ("Cat1 should have 1 HingeJoint2D, but has " + joints.Length);
    }
```

How do I correct the auto formatting?

Comment: Did you get it fixed? I was trying to help you and while playing with `policies` I managed to cause the same problem on my MonoDevelop. I had to find a new solution, should I post it?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the default by going to:

> tools -> custom policies -> default

That should allow you to go back to the default formatting.